# The image size does not match the pixel

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

There is image with the size `200x100`. However, when I want to get the RGB value of the last pixel by using

```
int c = image.getRGB(200, 100);
```

It appears an error.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
```

I want to ask whether the problem is the pixel width. If YES, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arrays are zero indexed, use:

```
int c = image.getRGB(199, 99);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pixels are indexed from zero.
Try

```
int c = image.getRGB(199, 99);
```